# Ошибка скомпилированной с помощью Nuitka программы на Python

Tags: python, nuitka

У меня возникла проблема скомпилированной с помощью Nuitka программы на Python 3.8
https://github.com/CineEncoder/cine-encoder/tree/master/cine_encoder с использованием PyQt5 и QProcess (с которым, как мне кажется, и связана проблема),
скомпилированная программа аварийно закрывается, вот вывод консоли:

```
[helg@Houston ~]$ /run/media/helg/GOODRAM-SDB/MakePackage/BIN/Linux/cine-encoder-2.4_other_linux_x86_64/App/CineEncoder.run 
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 684, resource id: 14689761, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/helg/GOODRAM-SDB/MakePackage/BIN/Linux/cine-encoder-2.4_other_linux_x86_64/App/main.py", line 1104, in progress_1
TypeError: 'compiled_method' object is not connected
Aborted (core dumped)
[helg@Houston ~]$
```

Как мне кажется, ошибка соответствует этим строкам кода Python (в файле main.py):

```
...
1135   if (percent >= 50) and (calling_pr_1 is True):
1136        self.procedure_1.finished.disconnect(self.error)
1137        self.procedure_1.finished.connect(self.add_metadata)
1138        calling_pr_1 = False
...
```

При том, что при запуске оригинальной версии программы через Python 3.8, никаких ошибок нет.

Для компиляции я использовал команду:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=qt-plugins main.py
```

Вот ссылка к скомпилированной программе: https://github.com/CineEncoder/cine-encoder/releases/download/2.4/cine-encoder-2.4_other_linux_x86_64.zip

Версии приложений:

```
[helg@Houston ~]$   python -m nuitka --version
0.6.8
Python: 3.8.5 (default, Sep  5 2020, 10:50:12) 
Executable: /usr/bin/python
OS: Linux
Arch: x86_64
```